# Cayley Graphs and Cyclically reduced words

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ be a symmetric generating set for $G$. (EDIT: Assume $S$ does not contain involutions!) Cyclically reduced words can be thought of as minimal length representatives of their conjugacy class in $Free(S)$. I am interested in certain properties of cyclically reduced words over $S$ and the values they correspond to in $G$.

1) Can every $g \in G$ be represented by a cyclically reduced word over $S$? Every element of $G$ can certainly be expressed as a reduced word over $S$ (simply because the Cayley graph $Cay(G,S)$ is connected, as $S$ is a symmetric generating set). But is this true for (the more restricted) cyclically reduced words too?

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, the answer is yes.

2) The total number of cyclically reduced words of length $k$ over $S$ with $|S|=2m$ is
$$(2m-1)^k + m + (m-1)(-1)^k$$
as shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825830/reduced-words-of-length-l?rq=1 and the references mentioned. But suppose I want to know how many cyclically reduced words evaluate to a specific element $g \in G$, then is there some closed form expression for this?

For instance, if we are interested in the number of reduced words of length $k$ that map to a particular element of $G$, then we can write this out using the non-backtracking operator on the adjacency matrix of $Cay(G,S)$. This is because the sequence of directed edges on a non-backtracking walk on the Cayley graph can be interpreted as a reduced word over $S$. Using known properties of non-backtracking walks as discussed in [What does this connection between Chebyshev, Ramanujan, Ihara and Riemann mean?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226925/what-does-this-connection-between-chebyshev-ramanujan-ihara-and-riemann-mean)
this problem of reduced words can be dealt in a fully combinatorial fashion.

However, cyclically reduced words involve more delicate properties of the group and generating set (or labelled edges in the Cayley graph). But I am curious if we can construct some $|G| \times |G|$ matrix 
$$B_k$$
such that for every $g_1,g_2 \in G$,
$$(B_k)_{g_1,g_2} = \#\{\text{cyclically reduced words of length k that evaluate to } g_2g_1^{-1}\}$$
on the lines of the similar analysis of reduced walks using non-backtracking operators.

Also posted on MathSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322707/cyclically-reduced-words-and-cayley-graphs

Comment: For 2, use that the cyclically reduced words form a regular language and the set of words representing a given element of a finite group is a regular language.  Build the automaton for the intersection of these languages and use the adjacency matrix for the automaton.

Comment: For 1, since the group is finite, there is no need to use any inverses of generators, so the answer is apparently  yes. But I am unclear how you are regarding involutory generators. Would you regard the word $aba$ in the group $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1, aba=bab \rangle$ as being cyclically reduced?

Comment: DerekHolt, Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited it to ensure there are no involutions in S, just to be safe. 

@BenjaminSteinberg Interesting direction, but is it really a regular language? Since cyclically reduced-ness depends on elements at both ends of a word not being inverses, I thought its context-free. Anyway, a bit rusty on this, and will check again.

Comment: @BharatRam, cyclically reduced should just mean that the last letter is not the inverse of the first.

Comment: If there are no involutory generators,then, as I explained in my previous comment, the answer to 1) is clearly yes.

Comment: Benjamin and Derek: Thanks. I'll look up and think to understand why/how your answers work, with the details. Is this well-studied? And could you suggest any relevant references?

Comment: It is not appropriate to cross-post on both math.se and MO.  Also, as Derek points out your first question is trivial.  I have voted to close.

Comment: @AndyPutman Sorry, will take one of them down based on suggestions. I had posted to SE only after the comments which hinted at the questions not being too non-trivial. However, that doesn't answer the questions. Also, if the first part is trivial, I can always edit it out. The second part is still open. So why close?

Comment: @BharatRam: Ben Steinberg explained how to find a closed form solution using finite state automata.  For a general finite group, you're not going to get a better answer.